# How can I detect if the height of the keyboard has changed in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8, uikeyboard

On iOS 8, keyboards can be different heights.  When the user switches between keyboards, or changes the height of the current keyboard, how can I detect this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listen to the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notification.

Use `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` values in the passed `userInfo` dictionary to retrieve the current and future frame of the keyboard.